# Making a program to compute the sum in python

Tags: python

I am making a program in Python to compute the sum of squares of number from 1-100.
i tried using this

```
total = sum(int [(el**2) for el in range(1, 101)])
```

i get an error stating that the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @falsetru thanks for the answer.
what is the difference between [] and () ?

Comment: [el**2 for el in range(1, 101)] returns a list, wheather (el**2 for el in range(1, 101)) returns a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error explanation - the int conversion is set on the entire list and list cannot be converted to int. The conversion is not needed in this case because all your variables are integers but if you do want to use it. Use it either on the sum or on each part of the sum (int(el**2))

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the parenthesis or the call to `int`:

```
>>> sum([el**2 for el in range(1, 101)])
338350
```

You don't even need the brackets:

```
>>> sum(el**2 for el in range(1, 101))
338350
```

You could also [use math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number):

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
    return (n * (n + 1) * ((2 * n) + 1))/6

>>> sum_of_squares(100)
338350
```

Comment: *You could also use math*: touché

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
sum([int(el**2) for el in range(1, 101)])
```

Note that `int()` goes **inside** the `[...]` list comprehension.

Or simpler:

```
sum(int(el**2) for el in range(1, 101))
```

because you don't need to create a full list for `sum()`.

Better yet, drop the `int()` call altogether, the exponent of an integer is still an integer:

```
sum(el ** 2 for el in range(1, 101))
```

Demo:

```
>>> sum(el ** 2 for el in range(1, 101))
338350
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `int`:

```
total = sum([(el**2) for el in range(1, 101)])
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are great. Just as a side note:

```
def sum_of_squares(end):
    return end * (end+1) * (2*end + 1) / 6

total = sum_of_squares(100)
```

The formula is a special case of more general Faulhaber's formula:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples

Comment: The calculation should be `total = sum_of_squares(100)`

Comment: @InbarRose Yep, fixed that.